# Open a file that does not exist with applicationContext.assets.open on android sunflower app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, inputstream, android-workmanager

In the sunflower app,
https://github.com/android/sunflower
there is a work manager request to prepopulate the data from a file
here's the worker:

```
 package com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.workers


class SeedDatabaseWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
        try {
            applicationContext.assets.open(PLANT_DATA_FILENAME).use { inputStream ->
                JsonReader(inputStream.reader()).use { jsonReader ->
                    val plantType = object : TypeToken<List<Plant>>() {}.type
                    val plantList: List<Plant> = Gson().fromJson(jsonReader, plantType)

                    val database = AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
                    database.plantDao().insertAll(plantList)

                    Result.success()
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error seeding database", ex)
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SeedDatabaseWorker"
    }
}
```

this code doesn't create the file which will be used to prepopulate the database, also it is not created else where in the app, so what if the file doesn't exist? it is not clear from the doc. of the open function what will happen
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)

Comment: ok I'll edit the question

Comment: unfortunately, i can't really help with your actual question, but i'm sure someone will be able to help you out

Comment: Files in assets are read only and are resources as the developer put them in assets directory using its IDE.  If the file does not exist you will get null or an exception. I dont know. You can find out easily. It will certainly not be created as assets is read only.

Comment: yes thanks @blackapps ..I found it..I though that it should be created elsewhere ...thanks again